# Deleting an Array of Pointers - Am I doing it right?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I feel a little stupid for making a question about the deletion of pointers but I need to make sure I'm deleting in the correct way as I'm currently going through the debugging process of my program.

Basically I have a few arrays of pointers which are defined in my header file as follows:

```
AsteroidView *_asteroidView[16];
```

In a for loop I then initialise them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)  
{  
      _asteroidView[i] = new AsteroidView();  
}
```

Ok, so far so good, everything works fine.
When I eventually need to delete these in the destructor I use this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)  
{  
        delete _asteroidView[i];  
}
```

Is this all I need to do? I feel like it is, but I'm worried about getting memory leaks.

Out of interest...
Is there much of a difference between an Array of Points to Objects compared with an Array of Objects?

Comment: Yes it's fine - you won't leak memory.

Comment: Consider using an array of smart pointers, that way you don't need to write the loop in the destructor.

Comment: Don;t declare variables with a leading underscore in the global scope (these identifiers are reserved for the implementation). It is unlikely that the implementation uses the identifier _asteroidView but it is a bad habit you should break now.

Comment: It works (though not exception safe). But the real question is do you need to dynamically allocate the AsteroidView? Without more context it is hard to tell if this (or @Space_V0wb0y solution is the best).

Comment: Martin, they are private, not global variables... sorry I didn't make that clear in my post. I probably don't need to dynamically allocate it to be honest...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is correct. However, you may want to consider using [Boost.PointerContainer](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), and save you hassle the hassle of manual resource management:

```
boost::ptr_vector<AsteroidView> _asteroidView;
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    _asteroidView.push_back(new AsteroidView());
}
```

You do not have to manage the deletion, the container does that for you. This technique is called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), and you should learn about it if you want to have fun using C++ :)

**About your edit:** There are several difference, but I guess the most important are these:

1. An array of pointers can contain objects of different types, if these are subclasses of the array type.
2. An array of objects does not need any deletion, all objects are destroyed when the array is destroyed.

Comment: +1 for managed deallocation. He could also consider simply using `std::vector` or `boost::scoped_array`

Comment: Thanks for the help, glad I'm doing it right. Will have a look into Boost.

Comment: @AJG85
Was going to use std::vector but never got around to changing everything. Might change it after I'm sure everything is working.

Answer (score 7):

It's absolutely fine.

The **rule of thumb** is: *match each call to `new` with an appropriate call to `delete` (and each call to `new[]` with a call to `delete[]`)*

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure I needed an extra delete[] at the end because it was an array. Glad I'm doing it right, thanks for the help :)

Comment: You would have needed `delete[]` only if you had allocated the array itself using `new[]` - so all is fine.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this all I need to do? I feel like it is, but I'm worried about getting memory leaks.

Yes. The program is deallocating resources correctly. No memory leaks :)

---

If you are comfortable with using `std::vector`( infact it is easy ), it does the deallocation process when it goes out of scope. However, the type should be of -

```
std::vector<AsteroidView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a class:

```
// this class has hidden data and no methods other than the constructor/destructor
// obviously it's not ready for prime time
class Foo {
    int* bar_[16];

    public:
    Foo()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            bar_[i] = new int;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        for (unsigned int i= 0; i < 16; ++i)
            delete bar_[i];
    }
};
```

You won't leak memory **if the constructor completes correctly**.  However, if `new` fails fails in the constructor (`new` throws a `std::bad_alloc` if you're out of memory), **[then the destructor is not run](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10)**, and you **will** have a memory leak.  If that bothers you, you will have to make the constructor exception safe (say, add a `try` ... `catch` block around the constructor, use RAII).  Personally, I would just use the Boost Pointer Container if the elements in the array must be pointers, and a `std::vector` if not.

Comment: I guess the elements don't have to be pointers... I'm not really sure why I made them that way in the first place. Sorry, I do have try catches in there, I just didn't think they were necessary to include in the post.

Comment: It's just something you need to be aware of.  The main reason the items would be pointers would be if `AsteroidView` were a base class and the container could hold objects derived from `AsteroidView`.